# How to retrieve current vertices position of triangles

Tags: opengl

I have piece of code which are following:

```
 glRotatef(triangle_info.struct_triangle.rot, 0, 0, 1.);

 glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

 glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, trian_data_values);

 glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
```

I want to know each VERTEX position after each transformation. How will I do this?

Answer (score 3):

There is no easy way to get to this data. OpenGL is mostly concerned with drawing, and you normally don't need that data, it will still draw fine. Applications that do need this data usually do the math themselves.

You will either have to do the transform manually, for each vertex. To do this, multiply each vertex with the modelview matrix. If you don't know the modelview matrix (a program needing to do this calculation would normally cache that value), you can query it with `glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX)`.

Alternatively, you can use transform feedback if either your OpenGL version is at least 3.0 or [EXT_transform_feedback](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/transform_feedback.txt) is supported. That will require you to create and bind a buffer, set the vertex positions as feedback varyings, and call begin/end transform feedback. Lastly, you have to map the buffer to get your data back.
Transform feedback is more setup, but spares you from doing the math yourself.